# Configure JavaFX with netbeans 11

Tags: java, javafx

I have downloaded the JavaFX SDK but I have heard there is something I need to put in the XML file or something like that?

I have done some research on youtube and google and I cannot find a definitive answer to how to set up a JavaFX project in netbeans, just wondering if someone can walk me through the steps.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You need to find 'Java' directory, where you have JDK & JRE.
I have it at: "C:/Program Files/Java/".
And there put whole file with it.